# dockerizing a legacy python application

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have an application which I'm trying to expose via docker-compose.  I've figured out all of the services/volumes necessary for the application except one component which is an awful bit of legacy code, that I don't currently have time/resources to update.

Basically, it is a python app which isn't pip installable but rather gets installed via a git clone, and its setup involves running some ad hoc shell and Python code.  To make matters worse, the logs/config files are stored in a subdir of the `src` tree - don't ask...

Anyway, I'm wondering if the solution (below) I've come up with sounds reasonable or if anyone has any better suggestions.

my (ad-hoc) solution:  install the app into a docker data volume, and create a service of which multiple instances would simply be running the Python executable on the data volume, along with parameters specifying which config files (also on the volume) to use.

EDIT: this is what I'm thinking currently regarding a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql # or probably a more specific mysql image
    volumes:
       # add stuff regarding db_data volume
    # probably some config as well

  msg_queue:
    image: redis
    # probably more config necessary  

   myapp: 
    image:  # some custom image I create elsewhere which exposes my django app via uswgi
    volumes:  # provide config the volumes it requires

  web: # for serving static/media files, reverse-proxy, load balancing 
    image: nginx
    # again more config necessary

  tutor: # the legacy chatbot code which communicate with myapp via msg_queue, also makes use of db
     image: # custom image I create elsewhere
     volumes: #config necessary for tutor_data

volumes:
  logs:
  web_content:
  tutor_content:
  db_data:
```

I figure I need to add some `depends_on`'s, and a bit more stuff, but hopefully this clarifies what I'm *attempting* to do. Does this clarify my question enough?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: This really seems too broad. Do you have any particular troubles or doubts about this approach?

Comment: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._ The impressive thing about Docker is that it increments and then _multiplies_ your problems. I don't know if anyone will be able to provide useful feedback without actual details regarding your deployment environment, but it seems to me you're adding complexity to maintaining a legacy system, and you're going to end up maintaining a legacy deployment workflow that runs legacy software. Running a Python 'executable' just does not have to be this involved.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, I figured as much.  Basically the executable is a long running python process, but not a proper service.  each instance of the executable I'd be running is basically a chatbot with different configuration so it can act as a physics tutor for a different phyiscs problem.  I *think* my solution *should* work, but I'm sure it doesn't use best practices.  I imagine there is no best practice in this case though

Comment: Your solution is exactly how you should *not* use docker. An application should be running in a container created from an image. So, you should write a `Dockerfile` that will recreate the installation process even if it is complex.

Comment: @KlausD.yeah, I hear ya.  regarding the subdirectory within the src dir where the log files/config are stored, do you think that it would be ok if I merely made it a symlink to a data volume so that would be persisted?  such a change to the ad-hoc setup scripts would be minimal

Comment: @kungphu I understand the idea that the hammer isn't the tool you want to use for all tasks.  docker seems to look like it will fit for all the other parts of my application but if I go that route, I *think* this legacy bit will also need to be containerized, which as you say complicates things.  I guess I'll need to make an edit to provide more info

Comment: better to installed from git at run time or post your finiding so will that narrow down the question scope

Comment: @KlausD. so if I'm understanding correctly, the image I'd be creating for this container would, in it's Dockerfile, pull in the source code, run it's setup script, which creates an empty the 'data' dir (unfortunately within it's src tree) and then map the data volume where I want the configs/logs onto that directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your ad-hoc solution seems reasonable.

However, I'd just create an image of this particular legacy app and have other docker containers that needing this app FROM it (provided that these other containers need a different python version than this legacy app).

It is just a preference.

Comment: yeah, I've added that bit where my 'tutor' service uses the image created by another Dockerfile elsewhere and have make use of a data volume for the logs/config.  not sure if this is the complete solution to my issue yet, which is why I haven't accepted this as the answer just yet. thx